# webexception httprequest

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am wondering in what cases, there will be webexception thrown out?

I know 503 etc and Timeout will be considered as webexception, but I am wondering if I can get the complete list somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to HTTP status codes?  [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Here is a [list of WebException.Status codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your list. But I want to know the relationship of HTTP status code with the WebException.status code. For example, will HTTP 401 results in a web exception?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if an exhaustive list exists somewhere, but simply put it would occur for any connectivity and network issue.
The list mentioned by Mitch Wheat is something to look at.